# Drupal 8: Showing the child taxonomy terms where the parent taxonomy term is displayed

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I am currently displaying a taxonomy entity reference field. This is the full entity, with all fields. Now, all the fields of this term are displayed on the page. But the underlying child terms are not. Is there any way to show the child terms alongside with the rest of the parent term fields on to the page? Thanks in advance.

[image: Manage display tab]

[image: Taxonomy list]

Answer (score 0):

I am understanding you to mean that you have a field on a node (or some other entity) that is an entity reference and you have the widget for that field in the display configuration set to rendered entity.

If so, there are a few ways to get to what you want, but they are all variations on the idea of taking the taxonomy term view (or a copy/derivative) of it and exposing it on the display mode for the term when you render it on that entity. You could do that by adding a viewfield on to your taxonomy term and defaulting it to that view. You could also do it by using the Twig tweak module and using drupal_view() in the template for that display mode.

I would probably lean toward the latter. drupal_view() is really just a wrapper around views_embed_view() so you don't really need Twig tweak, but I find that it makes for cleaner templates.